# How a concrete/brick storm drain is made?

Tags: brick, drains

This must be really simple, but I havent found any instructions and I'm unsure on how to proceed.

I need to make two storm drains (concrete boxes with grills on top and a pipe to direct rain water), from what I can imagine, I must lay a concrete slab, then lay the bricks, plaster the bricks with cement/sand/waterproof-additive. Is that it?

I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Very often in US commercial settings the components are precast concrete and the grates are from industrial supply companies.

Comment: In Brazil there are some precast concrete, but they are usually square. I need to make one that is about 20cm wide and 2m long (and 30 cm deep). I looked around but was unable to find it in joinable pieces. Oh, the grates I do find here in any size I need.

Comment: Typically there is a drain field of some sort involved so the grate at the top only acts as a emergency relief for long lasting heavy rains. The company I used to work for used the grate as the relief, but also a way to clear out debris that would eventually clog the system. Or are these to serve as area drains to collect surface water and send it somewhere else?

Comment: They are area drains. I didnt know how they were called and assume it was a storm drain

Comment: What kind of load will be on the surface?  Will vehicles be driving over it?

Comment: No vehicles, but a cart about 200+ kg will pass over it from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many manufactured options for channel shaped [surface drainage equipment](http://www.wholesaleplumbing.com/landscape-drainage/driveway-trench-channel-drains.html) that you should not have to create one from scratch. Search the internet.
If you must create your own, your method with the slab and brick should work, or make some wood forms and make it entirely out of concrete. Make sure the surrounding soil is firm and compacted to support it or it may move or crack. And [reinforce the concrete](https://www.google.com/search?q=reinforced%20concrete&espv=2&tbm=isch&imgil=QQhG-adPVXH0zM%253A%253B6xbD3-4h0msVgM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.theguardian.com%25252Fartanddesign%25252Fgallery%25252F2011%25252Fsep%25252F11%25252Fcontemporary-buildings-spotters-guide&source=iu&usg=__P-kTtc0NfUgRWHkTXIkF_YGW_oE%3D&sa=X&ei=wQrdU6j1E8XZoATVn4BQ&ved=0CC0Q9QEwAg&biw=1280&bih=923#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=QQhG-adPVXH0zM%253A%3B6xbD3-4h0msVgM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fstatic.guim.co.uk%252Fsys-images%252FGuardian%252FPix%252Fgallery%252F2011%252F9%252F2%252F1314984141317%252FReinforced-concrete-002.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.theguardian.com%252Fartanddesign%252Fgallery%252F2011%252Fsep%252F11%252Fcontemporary-buildings-spotters-guide%3B400%3B460).